# Chromebook and GoToMyPC Android app

Tags: android, chromebook, gotomypc

I have heard of people using the GoToMyPC Android app on Chromebook but would like to know if it works only on specific hardware. Was any sort of special configuration required to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

To get it working natively, check your hardware on https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps, which lists the Chrome OS hardware that are either already or planned to be capable of running Android apps in general.

I believe there's a developer's mode that you can set Chrome OS to get around the limitation (which allows only 1 app at a time.)  I'm sure you can find more info on that on the web, but I'd rather wait for a more stable and 'permanent' solution.  I have an Asus Chromebit that's to be a guestroom/travel/family gathering video/pic-showing PC, so GoToMyPC isn't top priority as yet.  Chromebit, as yet, is listed as 'planned' on the Chromium site.